# Как правильно находить класс и удалять его при отведении мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-event

При нажатии на кнопку вылезает sidebar, при помощи добавления одному div внутри body переключает класс на context-sidebar-active. 
Я хочу при отводе мыши от sidebar изменять класс на context-sidebar.
Сделал так, но не работает

```
if($('div').hasClass("context-sidebar-active")){
  $(".group-side-context").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("context-sidebar-active").addClass("context-sidebar");
  })
};
```

Класс group-side-context содержит весь размер sidebar, по этому при отводе от него мыши, я хочу закрывать sidebar. Где я ошибся ?

Comment: Без полного кода сложно сказать что-то определенное. Но предположу, что не надо создавать обработчик события `mouseleave` в условии.

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в том, что он проверяет наличие класса, только при создании страницы, а затем когда я уже создаю этот класс при помощи клика, он уже ничего делать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".group-side-context").mouseover){
$(".group-side-context").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".group-side-context").parent().removeClass("context-sidebar-active").addClass("context-sidebar-close").removeClass("context-sidebar-close").addClass("context-sidebar");
  })
};
```

Всё заработало